# One to Many BD - foriegn key & updates - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app i have a two models model customer (id, name, email) and cars(id, model, year).

customer has many cars
cars belong to customer

1) I want to add the customer id field to the cars model. Will adding t.integer :customer_id to the migration file be enough?

2) Once added how would i start populating the said cars db?

(I just started on rails last week so would appreciate any help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add to your existing migration, but a more common workflow is to create a second migration to change an existing table.

Read about [Rails Migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) for all the details.

1. Make a migration

   ```
   rails generate migration add-customer-id-to-cars
   ```
2. Add the correct code

   ```
   class AddCustomerIdToCars < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       add_column :cars, :customer_id, :integer
     end
   end
   ```
3. Migrate

   ```
   rake db:migrate
   ```
4. Add the association in `car.rb`

   ```
   class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
     # Your Car code

     belongs_to :customer
   end
   ```
5. Add the inverse association in your `customer.rb`

   ```
   class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
     # Your Customer code

     has_many :cars
   end
   ```

Comment: Thank you! i will try both ways suggested here :)

Comment: If i wanted to add a new car to a user i will have: @ car = @ customer.car.build ? in a new controller?

Comment: You will have to set the relationship in the reverse, I will edit my post to demonstrate that. Then you can do `car = @customer.cars.build`

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes. Though it would be more idiomatic to use `t.references`.

From [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (adapted to context):

> Using t.integer :customer_id makes the foreign key naming obvious and
>   explicit. In current versions of Rails, you can abstract away this
>   implementation detail by using t.references :customer instead.

You will also need to specify the associations in the model file.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

(2) You can use something like:

```
customer = Customer.find(id)
car = customer.cars.new
car.model = "some model"
car.save!
```